# Where is the workspace/build/libs located once I build and assemble my java project using gradle on Google Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, cloud, google-cloud-build

I am trying to automate the CI / CD process on google cloud build. I need to start the build as soon as I commit to the github repository and then run the test cases and make a jar file and then push it in a container on google cloud registry so I can further deploy it on Kubernetes. I have done the part till assembling the jar from here https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/build-java
But I can't find my jar file in the workspace/build/libs directory.

Comment: Can you share more code? how to help you if we don't know what you do!

Comment: Can you share the build files?, otherwise its difficult to understand the context.